# Execute the loop body for added elements to the list

Tags: java, collections

I would like to add elements in a loop to a list in such a way that the loop body will execute also for them. I know that this technique is very common in order to prevent `ConcurrentModificationException`:

```
List<Element> thingsToBeAdd = new ArrayList<Element>();
for(Iterator<Element> it = mElements.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    Element element = it.next();
    if(...) {  
         //irrelevant stuff..
        if(element.cFlag){
            // mElements.add(new Element("crack",getResources(), (int)touchX,(int)touchY));
            thingsToBeAdd.add(new Element("crack",getResources(), (int)touchX,(int)touchY));
            element.cFlag = false;
       }           
   }
}
mElements.addAll(thingsToBeAdd );
```

Unfortunately it doesn't execute the loop for the new elements.

Edit:

```
List<Element> thingsToBeAdd = new ArrayList<Element>();
for(Iterator<Element> it = mElements.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    Element element = it.next();
    if(...) {  
        //irrelevant stuff..
        if(element.cFlag){
            // mElements.add(new Element("crack",getResources(), (int)touchX,(int)touchY));
            thingsToBeAdd.add(new Element("crack",getResources(), (int)touchX,(int)touchY));
            element.cFlag = false;
       }           
   }
   mElements.addAll(thingsToBeAdd );
}
```

This will result in `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achived my goal using recursion:

```
private List<Element> executeForEachElement(List<Element> oldList)
    List<Element> newElements = new LinkedList<Element>();
    for (Element elem : oldList {
            newElements.addAll(generateNewElements(elem));
    }
    if (!newElements.isEmpty()) {
        oldList.addAll(executeForEachElement(newElements));
    }

    return oldList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

aren't you adding elements in the `mElements` after completion of loop

```
mElements.addAll(thingsToBeAdd );
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. If I add all elements in the loop I would have `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: In this code I added new elements to the list. I would like to add them is such way that the instructions in a loop will execute also for the new elements.

Comment: then you need to add the elements in the loop so while iterating it it will iterate through newly added element as well

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `CopyOnWriteArrayList`?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html